# CSS margin terror; Margin adds space outside parent element

Tags: html, css, overflow, margin

My css margins doesn't behave the way I want or expect them to. I seems like my header margin-top affect the div-tags surrounding it.

**This is what I want and expect:**
[image: What I want....]

**...but this is what I end up with:**
[image: What I get...]

**Source:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Margin test</title>

<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin:0;
}
#page {
    margin:0;
    background:#FF9;
}
#page_container {
    margin:0 20px;
}
h1 {
    margin:50px 0 0 0;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="page">
    <div id="page_container">
        <header id="branding" role="banner">
            <hgroup>
                <h1 id="site-title"><span><a href="#" title="Title" rel="home">Title</a></span></h1>
                <h2 id="site-description">Description</h2>
            </hgroup>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have exaggerated the margin in this example. Default browser margin on h1-tag is somewhat smaller, and in my case I use *Twitter Bootstrap, with Normalizer.css* which sets default margin to 10px. Not that important, main point is; I can not, should not, *want not* change the margin on the h1-tag.

I guess it is similar to my other question; *[Why does this CSS margin-top style not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9519841/266642)*. Question is how do I solve this specific issue?

I have read [a few threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7742720/266642) on similar problems, but haven't found any real answers and solutions. I know adding `padding:1px;` or `border:1px;` solves the problem. But that only adds new problems, since I do not want a padding nor a border on my div-tags.

There must be a better, best practice, solution? This must be pretty common.

Comment: Did you start with a CSS reset?

Comment: I use Normalizer.css. But that is not the issue. If i remove the h1-tag. There is no problem. Problem is that i want a margin on my h1-tag and that is affecting the surrounding elements.

Comment: Can you [post a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) by any chance?

Comment: @DavidThomas I'm playing with a demo at the moment if you want to fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5RhFq/6/

Comment: never mind.. j08691 has solved it :) http://jsfiddle.net/5RhFq/7/

Comment: The explanation and some possible solutions were already covered in my answer to your previous question...

Answer (score 273, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto` to your `#page` div.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/464jW/)**

And check out [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) while you're at it.

Comment: That works. Found loads of examples here ( http://www.seifi.org/css/understanding-taming-collapsing-margins-in-css.html ) aswell and some good explaining. No solution is really 100% satisfying. But I guess one just have to live with it, margin must work this way or text formatting would be impossible. 99% of time it works as needed. But every now and then comes the issue when designing a layout. :P

Comment: overflow:hidden; also worked for me and worked better for me in my scenario.

Comment: Collapsing margins look incredibly complicated to define (many rules, many exceptions), what's it use?

Comment: `display: flex` with `flex-direction: column` on parent container does the same trick.

Answer (score 61):

Add any one of the following rules:

```
float: left/right;
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
overflow: auto/scroll/hidden;
```

This is caused by `collapsing margins`. See an article about this behavior [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/collapsing-margins/).

According to the article:

> The W3C specification defines collapsing margins as follows:
>
> “In this specification, the expression collapsing margins means that adjoining  margins (no non-empty content, padding, or border areas, or clearance separate them) of two or more boxes (which may be next to one another or nested) combine to form a single margin.”

This is also true for parent-child elements.

All the answers include one of the possible solutions:

> There are other situations where elements do not have their margins collapsed:

- floated elements
- absolutely positioned elements
- inline-block elements
- elements with overflow set to anything other than visible (They do not collapse margins with their children.)
- cleared elements (They do not collapse their top margins with their parent block’s bottom margin.)
- the root element

Comment: `clear: <any option>` does not seem to work, the other solutions work on Google Chrome

Answer (score 22):

Problem was the parent not taking into account children for height. Adding `display:inline-block;` did it for me.

**Full CSS**

```
#page {
    margin:0;
    background:#FF9;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M3Mu6/)

Answer (score 5):

Just add `border-top: 1px solid transparent;` to your `#page` element.

[From w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

> Two margins are adjoining if and only if:
>   - no line boxes, no clearance, no padding and no border separate them

Comment: It worked for me. While I like the `overflow:auto;` solution better, i thought this was cool. I thought the reference to w3 would be useful, so I added it to your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Add the following rule:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

This is caused by collapsing margins. See an article about this behavior [here](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/why-there-is-a-white-space-above-header).

According to the article:

> If a parent element does not have any top padding or less top margin then its first child, then elements are rendered in a way that makes the parent element appear to have the child element's margin. So this can happen anywhere on a page where these conditions are met, but it tends to be most obvious at the top of a page.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions in the other answers didn't work for me. Transparent borders, inline-block, etc., all caused other problems. Instead, I added the following css to my ancestor element:

```
parent::after{
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Depending on your situation, this may cause its own problems because it adds extra space after the last child element.

Answer (score 0):

My approach when I was making styles for XenForo 2.1, but it should be useful for you:
(Please replace those LESS variables to your actual values. Also, the absolute value of minor margins shall be as same as the height of before-after pseudo elements.)

```
// The following two lines are to avoid top & bottom fieldset borders run out of the block body.
// (Do not tweak the CSS overflow settings, otherwise the editor menu won't be float above the block border.)
&:before {content: "\a0"; display: block; width: auto; margin-bottom: floor(-1 * @xf-lineHeightDefault * @xf-fontSizeSmall - @xf-borderSizeMinorFeature);}
&:after {content: "\a0"; display: block; width: auto; margin-top: floor(-1 * @xf-lineHeightDefault * @xf-fontSizeSmall - @xf-borderSizeMinorFeature);}
```

Comment: I saw your post about `sort` on MacOS, you can try to install `GNU sort`.

Comment: @Philippe Thanks. Sorry that my account level is not high enough to let me upvote a comment.

Comment: No worries, did you try `GNU sort` ?

Comment: @Philippe Same error: Illegal Byte Sequence.