# margin-top issue on HTML

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="template">
        <div class="box"></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

My CSS

```
.template{
    height:500px;
    width:1000px;
    background-color:#e1bfbe;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.box{
    height:420px;
    width:165px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    margin-left:416px;
    margin-right:417px;
    margin-top:37px;
    margin-bottom:38px;
}
```

Now I get the following output

[image]
but when I add `float:left;` in `.box` class I get the following image

[image]

only margin-top is not working without `float:left;` Why should I add `float:left` to get top margin for the element .box ?

Comment: Your margin is being used on the parent element. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element

Comment: Sounds like a case of collapsing margins.  Check this thread out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519841/why-does-this-css-margin-top-style-not-work

Comment: I dont need a fixed code, I would like to know the reason.......

Answer (score 2):

Here's a thread that describes the same problem: [CSS margin terror; Margin adds space outside parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573653/css-margin-terror-margin-adds-space-outside-parent-element)

It's a common issue with non-collapsing margins.

An alternative to adding `float: left` is `overflow: auto`

Answer (score 1):

Add **display: inline-block;** to.box class.

Comment: This is the better way to do it. A div is naturally inline, and you're using it as a block.

Comment: @Suresh Ponnukalai : yes div is naturally inline, because it doesn't force for new lines and takes up only as much width as it needs.

Comment: `div` are `block` elements by default.

Comment: @Suresh Ponnukalai : agree. my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your margin is being used on the parent element and this is an expected behavior. However, there are a few ways to get around it...

**Solution 1:** Float the `div`... This will contain the margins of child elements and prevent margin collapsing.

**Solution 2:** You could also add a non-breaking space on the parent `div`

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lswvgurf/)**

More info on collapsing margins can be found [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519933/3739658).

Answer (score 0):

Just add display:inline-block; to your box class margin-top would be again alive !

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q95jxgsm/)

**CSS**

```
.box {
    display:inline-block; /*Added */
    height:420px;
    width:165px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    margin-left:416px;
    margin-right:417px;
    margin-top:37px;
    margin-bottom:38px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this I have Modified your Style little bit

```css
html, body {
    margin:0;
}
.template {
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#e1bfbe;
    margin:0;
    float: left;
}
.box {
    height:420px;
    width:165px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    margin: 37px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="template">
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```