# How to have main intro div always show full width of window

Tags: html, css

How can I have my first div always be full-screen (of the browser not computer), and then supporting divs show underneath.

I want to replicate the layout of this site
http://checklandkindleysides.com

In the simplest form, I just want:

- First section to be full height and width of window
- Supporting content to be a specific size and not full-screen

Thanks

Comment: Good browsers provide in-built tools for analyzing the HTML elements and associated CSS

Comment: I know but I am a beginner and find their code quite hard to understand. I just want it simplified without all their extra code

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the `html`, `body` and `full height div` a height of 100%.

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.full-height-content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto; /* margin overflow fix */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="full-height-content">
    This is your full height content
</div>
<div class="page-content">
    <p>This is your standard page content</p>
</div>
```

Here is a codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNyQJm

Comment: Great, thanks, but there is a white margin at the top

Comment: That is due to the default margins on the <p> tag inside the main content. I have removed it and updated the codepen link. See the updated answer.

Comment: A better solution to the issue they just brought up is to use `overflow-y: auto;` on the `div` [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573653/css-margin-terror-margin-adds-space-outside-parent-element). The problem would otherwise return as soon as they try to add a margin to the inner element.

Comment: Cheers @4castle,  added to answer