# Blank space on top of website in Firefox, but not in Safari

Tags: html, css, space

I have made a simple web page. I can see no blank space when I open the website on safari, but on firefox, there is a gap that is probably 30px tall.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="background-color: blue;">
            <h1>hello</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS margin terror; Margin adds space outside parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573653/css-margin-terror-margin-adds-space-outside-parent-element)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the margin on the heading as well. For example:

```
body, h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```css
body, h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: blue;">
  <h1>hello</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make it easy for yourself and reset all margins/paddings in your CSS (won't affect elements);

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "won't affect elements"?

Comment: Like buttons and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Certain browsers will put margin around header tags. It's always a good idea to include a reset.css file on your site so that things appear how you want them to cross browsers.

[Here's](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) a simple reset.css file for you to include.