# Is it possible to target elements that have certain CSS stylings?

Tags: html, css

For example: a rule that makes all elements that have `display: block` have `overflow: auto`. This rule obviously has to take in the default styling of the browser as it's the browser that'll make so many elements display set to `block`.

This is to help escape the problem of collapsing margins!

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Short answer: No. Long answer: maaaaybe... but please don't. Also, we can't help much without having code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: There's no way to target those elements in CSS. There's a way to get those elements using the DOM/CSSOM, but it would be extremely resource-intense and would likely reduce your application to a crawl.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It would be to help the problem of collapsing margins (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573653/css-margin-terror-margin-adds-space-outside-parent-element)

Comment: You can target the elements that *most* browsers will default the `display` property to `block`, but not the ones that have been redefined. For instance, you could target `div`s, but if you had a class that applied to a `div` that had a rule `display: inline`, it would still be targeted by the hypothetical rule.

Comment: The "problem" of collapsing margins is solved by being aware of them and adjusting your rules to accommodate them, not put a fix in that would just have different side effects (including unwanted multiple scrollbars, perhaps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been in situations like yours many, many times where you can't change markup due to using a third party API, back end developers architect the backend a certain way etc and management needs something done. so I would do something like this:

```css
div[style="display: block"] {
  color: red;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: block">
  hey
</div>
```

Please note that this will only work if *the style your targeting is inline*

In terms of targeting an element with styles determined in a CSS file, I don't think that's possible.