# margin-top between child and its parent

Tags: html, css

I have two divs: `.content` and `.main-section`, the second inside the first. I am adding a `margin-top` to `.main-section` and I expected to see part of .content, but it seems this has a `margin-top` too. Why this behavior? and How to create a margin between `.content` and `.main-section`?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: peru;
}

.main-section {
  background: red;
  height: calc(100vh - 30px);
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="main-section">
    <p class="parragraph"> parragraph </p>
    <p class="parragraph"> parragraph </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Expected:**
[image: Expected]

**Output:**
[image: Output]

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573653/css-margin-terror-margin-adds-space-outside-parent-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573653/css-margin-terror-margin-adds-space-outside-parent-element) Related problem that can be solved with `overflow: auto`

Comment: Thanks @masterpreenz. I understand, The answer provided is the link is for CSS2. Also apply for current CSS?

Comment: yes it does apply to the current CSS.the CSS2 Spec will remain valid forever: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385583/8620333

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As *masterpreenz* said in the comment, use `overflow:auto` to solve this. You can read more here about it: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: peru;
  overflow: auto;
}

.main-section {
  background: red;
  height: calc(100vh - 30px);
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="main-section">
    <p class="parragraph"> parragraph </p>
    <p class="parragraph"> parragraph </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Right, the link is for CSS2. Also apply for actual CSS?

Answer (score 1):

you should set padding-top for your parent div to make it what you want

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: peru;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.main-section {
  background: red;
  height: calc(100vh - 30px);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="main-section">
    <p class="parragraph"> parragraph </p>
    <p class="parragraph"> parragraph </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use margin: top effect, then the main section can also go out of the content block if overflow condition is not specified, so it's better to use padding: which specifies that the main section will begin after the given value of padding: top.