# adding overflow: hidden; to an anchor element that has shadow causes other elements to move

Tags: html, css

First, I want to know why overflow hidden behaves like that. I am assuming here that overflow set to hidden will hide that inset shadow that I added.

```css
div {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.btn {
  padding: 12px 24px;
  background-color: aqua;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hover-effect {
  background-color: #fdf2e9;
}

.hover-effect:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0 2px rgb(1, 1, 1, 0.7), inset -2px -2px 0 2px rgb(1, 1, 1, 0.7);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas mollitia soluta pariatur vitae, sapiente neque cumque reprehenderit, asperiores rerum accusantium quis, eum dolor maiores necessitatibus aperiam quasi. Repudiandae, modi iure!
  </p>
  
  <a href="#" class="btn">Sign in</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn hover-effect">More info</a>
</div>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/13573653/1264804.