# White space next to wrapper div

Tags: html, css

I´m working on a small website that uses a `<div class="wrapper">` around its content.

Problem is, that a white space is added to the right and bottom, see screenshot:

[image]

My HTML looks like this, currently:

```css
    :root {
        --primary: #ddd;
        --dark: #333;
        --light: #fff;
        --shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(104, 104, 104, 0.8);
    }
    
    html * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    .wrapper {
        display: grid;
        min-height: 100vh;
        background-color: lightgray;  
    }
    
    .nav {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed;
        /*top: 15px;*/
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .nav > ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
        height: 45px;
        padding: 0;
        padding-top: 5px;
        box-shadow: var(--shadow);
        border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
        background-color: white;
    }
    
    .nav > ul > li{
        display: inline;
        float: left;
    }
    
    .nav a {
        color: dimgrey;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    
    .home {
        display: grid;
        margin: 5vh 5vh 5vh 5vh;
        margin-top: 65px;
        min-height: 90vh;
        cursor: default;
        color: dimgrey;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 16px;
        box-shadow: var(--shadow);
    }
    
    .text {
        border-radius: 16px;
    }
    
    .image {
        grid-area: image;
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url('schach.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        border-radius: 16px 0px 0px 16px;
    }
    
    .info {
        display: grid;
        margin: 5vh 5vh 5vh 5vh;
        margin-top: 65px;
        min-height: 90vh;
        background-color: white;
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url('code.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        cursor: default;
        color: dimgrey;
        border-radius: 16px;
        box-shadow: var(--shadow);
    }
    
    .headlines {
        text-align: right;
        font-weight: bold;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
        padding-top: 25px;
        box-shadow: var(--shadow);
        height: auto;
    }
    
    .contact {
        display: grid;
        margin: 5vh 5vh 5vh 5vh;
        margin-top: 65px;
        min-height: 90vh;
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url('oldphones.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        cursor: default;
        color: dimgrey;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 16px;
        box-shadow: var(--shadow);
    }
    
    .footer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .footer > ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
        box-shadow: var(--shadow);
        border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
        background-color: white;
    }
    
    .footer > ul > li {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
    }
    
    .footer a {
        color: dimgrey;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
        <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#home">
                    <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#info">
                    <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#contact">
                    <i class="fas fa-comments"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="wrapper">
        <span id="home"></span>
        <div class="home">
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="text">
                <div class="text_content">
                    <h4>headlinesmall</h4>
                    <h2>headlinebig</h2>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
                        sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore
                        magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et
                        accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
                        gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor
                        sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
                        elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
                        dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos
                        et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
                        gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <span id="info"></span>
        <div class="info">
            <p class="headlines">
                <span class="headlinesmall">headlinesmall</span><br />
                <span class="headlinebig">headlinebig</span><br /><br />
                <span class="info_text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
                    sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore
                    magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et
                    accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
                    gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor
                    sit amet.
                </span>
            </p>
    
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="slider_content">
                    <p class="slider_content_text">Label 01</p>
                    <p class="slider_content_text">Label 02</p>
                    <p class="slider_content_text">Label 03</p>
                    <p class="slider_content_text">Label 04</p>
                    <p class="slider_content_text">Label 05</p>
                    <p class="slider_content_text">Label 06</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <span id="contact"></span>
        <div class="contact">
            <div class="contactimage"></div>
            <form></form>
        </div>
    
        <div class="footer">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#home">
                        Datenschutz
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#info">
                        Impressum
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I of course tried to remove margins, paddings, set the min-width to 100% resp. 100vw, to work without a wrapper, removed box-sizing: border-box but I can´t find my mistake.

That small navigation box at the top takes the full device width, it is positioned outside the wrapper. When I put it inside the wrapper it takes the full width, too. But somehow removing the wrapper does not solve the problem, so I think the mistake must be placed somewhere at the wrappers´ content?

**EDIT:**
So I found out that setting the wrappers width to 111vw makes it fill out the white space, but I don´t see why. However, increasing the min-height of the wrapper does not result in removing the bottom white space.

**EDIT 2:**
The snippet seems to work here, so I tried different browsers like IE - width 100% does work there, but not in Chrome. What might be the reason, is the css faulty?

**EDIT 3:**
Might the problem be related to CSS Grid? The code behaves differently in any tested browser. Edge, IE, Firefox, Chrome...

Comment: I see no white space in your snippet

Comment: wtf, this is crazy... but the bottom space is there.

Comment: Try checking all paddings. Sometimes padding just push your content instead of creating space with wrapper. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742720/css-margin-pushing-the-body-element

Comment: Remove height from your `.footer`

Comment: right whitespace does not appear in your snippet. the bottom space is there because you set a `height:20px` on `.footer` which is smaller than the height it actually should have. Remove that height or set a bigger height ( at least equal to the buttons height ) and the bottom white space will dissapear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete in footer height: 20px;

```css
    :root {
        --primary: #ddd;
        --dark: #333;
        --light: #fff;
        --shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(104, 104, 104, 0.8);
    }
    
    html * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    .wrapper {
        display: grid;
        min-height: 100vh;
        background-color: lightgray;  
    }
    
    .nav {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed;
        /*top: 15px;*/
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .nav > ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
        height: 45px;
        padding: 0;
        padding-top: 5px;
        box-shadow: var(--shadow);
        border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
        background-color: white;
    }
    
    .nav > ul > li{
        display: inline;
        float: left;
    }
    
    .nav a {
        color: dimgrey;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    
    .home {
        display: grid;
        margin: 5vh 5vh 5vh 5vh;
        margin-top: 65px;
        min-height: 90vh;
        cursor: default;
        color: dimgrey;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 16px;
        box-shadow: var(--shadow);
    }
    
    .text {
        border-radius: 16px;
    }
    
    .image {
        grid-area: image;
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url('schach.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        border-radius: 16px 0px 0px 16px;
    }
    
    .info {
        display: grid;
        margin: 5vh 5vh 5vh 5vh;
        margin-top: 65px;
        min-height: 90vh;
        background-color: white;
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url('code.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        cursor: default;
        color: dimgrey;
        border-radius: 16px;
        box-shadow: var(--shadow);
    }
    
    .headlines {
        text-align: right;
        font-weight: bold;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
        padding-top: 25px;
        box-shadow: var(--shadow);
        height: auto;
    }
    
    .contact {
        display: grid;
        margin: 5vh 5vh 5vh 5vh;
        margin-top: 65px;
        min-height: 90vh;
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url('oldphones.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        cursor: default;
        color: dimgrey;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 16px;
        box-shadow: var(--shadow);
    }
    
    .footer {
        width: 100%;
 
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .footer > ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
        box-shadow: var(--shadow);
        border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
        background-color: white;
    }
    
    .footer > ul > li {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
    }
    
    .footer a {
        color: dimgrey;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
        <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#home">
                    <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#info">
                    <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#contact">
                    <i class="fas fa-comments"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="wrapper">
        <span id="home"></span>
        <div class="home">
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="text">
                <div class="text_content">
                    <h4>headlinesmall</h4>
                    <h2>headlinebig</h2>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
                        sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore
                        magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et
                        accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
                        gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor
                        sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
                        elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
                        dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos
                        et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
                        gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <span id="info"></span>
        <div class="info">
            <p class="headlines">
                <span class="headlinesmall">headlinesmall</span><br />
                <span class="headlinebig">headlinebig</span><br /><br />
                <span class="info_text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
                    sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore
                    magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et
                    accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
                    gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor
                    sit amet.
                </span>
            </p>
    
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="slider_content">
                    <p class="slider_content_text">Label 01</p>
                    <p class="slider_content_text">Label 02</p>
                    <p class="slider_content_text">Label 03</p>
                    <p class="slider_content_text">Label 04</p>
                    <p class="slider_content_text">Label 05</p>
                    <p class="slider_content_text">Label 06</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <span id="contact"></span>
        <div class="contact">
            <div class="contactimage"></div>
            <form></form>
        </div>
    
        <div class="footer">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#home">
                        Datenschutz
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#info">
                        Impressum
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, that´s it for the bottom border. Strange is, that I tried to run it in the browsers mentioned above, each showing a different behavior. Then I switched back to chrome and the border to the right is gone?!?