# Why is my body element smaller than my html element?

Tags: css, svelte

all my margins and padding are 0. In the `global.css` file I only have this small piece of code:

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[image: body size]

Here you can see the highlighted part of `<body>`. Note the fact that the body pixel size is `1261 x 876`.

[image: html size]

In the 2nd picture you can see that the `<html>` part also has the same pixel size of `1261 x 876`, **but** is highlighting the entire screen, without the white bar on top.

EDIT: I have checked the child elements inside the `<body>` for overflow. They had some overflow padding.

Comment: Check inside the body for an element with a margin that's overflowing its parent. See this question: [CSS margin pushing the body element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742720/css-margin-pushing-the-body-element)

Comment: What type of element is the 125?

Comment: resetcss is a good practice for these cases. https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: @Corrl The 125 is a simple <p>.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up, resetcss lead me to the answer. The answer was a child overflowing the parent element.